# Allow Non-Domain Computers To Access File Share But Require Authentication

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing, windows-server-2016

I would like to know how to setup a file share that non-domain computers can access but still be authenticated by the credentials they provide to see what folders and files they have access too (authorization).

*Example*

User Bob is on his personal PC and goes to \\SERVER to display the available shares in file explorer. Before shares being displayed a windows log-in prompt appears asking for credentials.

Comment: this is the default configuration as long as `everyone` doesn't have permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your NTFS and Share level permission at least `authenticated users` and remove the `everyone` permission groups

Answer (score 0):

1. active local guest user from computer management
2. in gpedit.msc, 
   Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
   Doube click "Access this computer from the network" and check that EVERYONE & GUEST is added to the list.
3. in CMD, gpupdate/force